# Can you detect a failed DLL load using ETW?

Tags: c#, etw

I'm trying to use ETW to detect failed library loads. In ProcMon, I'd set a filter for the CreateFile operation, set the path to end with .dll and the result to "NAME NOT FOUND". This captures an applications attempt to access a DLL which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to do this using ETW? I'm able to capture the successful library loads, but not failed loads.

Here's my code so far:

```
using(session = new TraceEventSession(sessionName, null))
{
    session.EnableKernelProvider(
        KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.ImageLoad |
        KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.Process,
        KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.None
        );

    using (TraceLogEventSource traceLogSource = TraceLog.CreateFromTraceEventSession(session))
    {
        Action<ImageLoadTraceData> PrintEvent = ((ImageLoadTraceData data) => Print(data));
        Action<FileIOReadWriteTraceData> PrintFileEvent = ((FileIOReadWriteTraceData data) => PrintFile(data));

        traceLogSource.Kernel.ImageLoad += PrintEvent;

        timer = new Timer(delegate (object state)
        {
            if (session != null)
                session.Dispose();
            session = null;
        }, null, monitoringTimeSec * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);

        traceLogSource.Process();
    }
}
```

And the PrintFile method for the ImageLoad event:

```
static void Print(ImageLoadTraceData data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[*] {0} loaded a library!", data.ProcessName);
    Console.WriteLine("\t {0}", data.FileName); 
}
```

This gives me output like this:

```
[*] GoogleUpdate loaded a library!
         C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll
```

I'd like to be able to capture only failed attempts to load a library. I could take each loaded event and work back up the DLL load order (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order), but that seems like an unnecessarily naive approach.